# Firebase Database index : information and effects

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, multi-index

[image]

I m using firebase Database .Planning to have quite a large data collection , I'm trying to use indexes . Making some tests, i don t know if rules i implement are correct let alone improve the queries .Is there a way to have a feedback on those indexations (correct or not, improve or not)

right now  i have one class as described in the picture and i have the created the following rule

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
      "users": {
       "$user_id": {
         ".indexOn": ["user_id", "username"]
          }
       },
 }
```

Since i get no  feedback from firebase, i don t know if this is correct and improves anything .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase's server-side rules are meaningless without seeing the code that exercises them.

But at a first glance it seems you're defining your indexes too low in the tree: indexes need to be defined at the location where you run the query. So if you want to run a query on `/users`, you need to define the indexes on `/users`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": ["user_id", "username"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Queries are numerous. Thanx for the information Frank. I was also looking  for a way to figure out the efficiency of the indexation but i guess there is no easy way to find out